# Bookmark system in django as in instagram

Tags: python, django, ajax

I wanna build this bookmarking system like in Instagram, I'm having problems writing the logic in views.py and displaying it. So what I want is to bookmark "Act" based on "act-id's" to Wishlist model if a user is authenticated and it would be better if we use Ajax for the post-call(when clicked on the bookmark icon) or open to new options really. Here's my current code... Please help me! if you need any extra bit of code just lemme know.

models.py

```
class Act(models.Model):
    label1 = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=False)
    label2 = models.ImageField(blank=False, null=True)
    label3 = models.IntegerField(('year'), choices=YEAR_CHOICES, default=datetime.datetime.now().year)
    label4 = models.CharField(max_length=80)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.Name

class Wishlist(models.Model):
    user_id = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True)
    act_id = models.ForeignKey(Act, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
```

views.py

```
@csrf_exempt
def wishlist(request):
    act_id = request.POST.get('act_id')
    if not act_id:
        raise ValueError("Required act_id to set wishlist")
    user_id = request.user.pk
    try:
        act_id = Act.objects.get(pk=act_id)
        wishlist_obj = {
                        'user_id': user_id,
                        'act_id': act_id
        }
        Wishlist(**wishlist_obj).save()
    except ObjectDoesNotExist:
        return HttpResponse('Some error occured, unable to add to wishlist')
    return HttpResponse('Added to wishlist')
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('signup/', views.signup, name='signup'),
    path('login/', views.login_req, name='login'),
    path("logout/", views.logout_req, name="logout"),
    path('home/', views.home, name='home'),
    path('wishlist/', views.wishlist, name='wishlist'),
]
```

for more context here's a conceptual pic of home.html
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lX8Ro.png

Comment: 1) You forgot to post the views code, 2) What is the question exactly?

Comment: @samu I didn't add the rest of the views.py code cause all it has is user registration and login and well I didn't add the wishlist function cause its broken and didn't wanted to confuse anyone, well I'm adding it now, hope that helps

Comment: 2. I want to create a bookmarking system similar to Instagram. like when someone clicks on the bookmark icon in the card, it saves that "Act" card(based on act_id) on Wishlist template if the user is authenticated or it just wants you to log in, hope that would help

Answer (score 0):

models.py

```
class Act(models.Model):
   label1 = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=False)
   label2 = models.ImageField(blank=False, null=True)
   label3 = models.IntegerField(('year'),choices=YEAR_CHOICES, default=datetime.datetime.now().year)
   label4 = models.CharField(max_length=80)

   def __str__(self):
    return self.Name

class Wishlist(models.Model):
   user_id = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True)
   act_id = models.ManyToManyField(Act,blank=True)
```

views.py

```
@csrf_exempt
def wishlist(request):
   act_id = request.POST.get('act_id')
   if not act_id:
     raise ValueError("Required act_id to set wishlist")

   wishlist_exist=Wishlist.objects.filter(user_id=request.user).exists()

   if wishlist_exist == False:
     user_wishlist = Wishlist.objects.create(user_id = request.user)
     user_wishlist.save()
   elif wishlist_exist == True:
     user_wishlist=Wishlist.objects.filter(user_id=request.user).first()

   user_wishlist.act_id.add(act_id)
```